# How to pass a form to PHP in appended/prepended div?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form with the problem:

(I cut down the codes to make it simple)

```
<form action="FOO.PHP" method="POST">
    <label for="numberofsteps">Number of steps</label>
    <input type="number" name="numberofsteps" />
    <input type="button" name="addsteps" value="Add Steps"/>
    <div id='prependarea'>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

This is the jquery part:

```
$('input[name=addsteps]').on('click',function(){
   var numberofsteps=$('input[name=numberofsteps]').val(); //example :5
   while(numberofsteps>0)
   {
      $('#prependarea').prepend("<div>somethinghere<form action='FOO.php' method='POST'>somethinghere</form></div>");
      numberofsteps-- ;
   }
});
```

It prepends the div and the form but when I submit the whole form, It doesn't POST the prepended form values.

Their action and method were the same.

It ignores the form inside the prepended div.

Any work arounds?

Comment: your string is broken here, `$('#prependarea').prepend("<div>somethinghere<form action="FOO.php" method="POST">somethinghere</form></div>"); 
` you need to escape the double quotes inside the string.

Comment: Oh yeah. as always typographical error. I'll edit immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you `prepending` a `form` you can `prepend` the `elements` like `input box, button chakboxes, radio button etc` only 
so the elements are available to your **parent form**

Also `escape double quotes` while you are `prepend` some `elements`

Answer (score 0):

Nested forms are not valid HTML. Even if you fix the quote syntax error, it still won't work.

Instead you should just prepend the input elements not the form element.

```
  $('#prependarea').prepend("<div>somethinghere <input type='text' /></div>");
```